# Regex to delete characters before a string

Tags: regex

I'm having a text file like this. It has more than **500 thousand lines**:

> ('12', '9', '56', 'Trojan.Genome.Win32.230770',
> '04df65889035a471f8346565600841af',
> '9190953854e36a248819e995078a060e0da2e687',
> 'b6488037431c283da6b9878969fecced695ca746afb738be49103bd57f37d4e4',
> '2015-10-16 00:00:00', 'Zillya', '16', 'TROJAN', 'trojan.png',
> '2016-01-14 21:35:44');  **#line1**
>
> ('13', '3', '54', 'UnclassifiedMalware',
> '069506a02c4562260c971c8244bef301',
> 'd08e90874401d6f77768dd3983d398d427e46716',
> '78e155e6a92d08cb1b180edfd4cc4aceeaa0f388cac5b0f44ab0af97518391a2',
> '2015-10-15 00:00:00', 'Comodo', '6', 'MALWARE', 'malware.png',
> '2016-01-14 21:35:44'); **#line2**

I only want to keep the text file into something like this:

> Trojan.Genome.Win32.230770, 04df65889035a471f8346565600841af,
> 9190953854e36a248819e995078a060e0da2e687,
> b6488037431c283da6b9878969fecced695ca746afb738be49103bd57f37d4e4
> **#line1**
>
> UnclassifiedMalware, 069506a02c4562260c971c8244bef301,
> d08e90874401d6f77768dd3983d398d427e46716,
> 78e155e6a92d08cb1b180edfd4cc4aceeaa0f388cac5b0f44ab0af97518391a2
> **#line2**

I have tried all of regex that I could think of but they didn't work.

Comment: It seems that you a comma separated structure,why dont you just split it  and remove not needed cells?

Comment: What engine / development environment?

Comment: @User1234 That is just the first two lines of the file. The file actually has more than 500 thousand lines!

Comment: @MichalM I'm working on C++

Comment: As user @User1234 says, tokenize the string with commas as separators. Construct new string from wanted tokens.

Comment: @Kusalananda Will it work with my text file?

Comment: Definitely. *If you write the code right*. (I'm a bit too busy to write up an answer right now).

Comment: You should show those regexes you've tried already in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is supposed to be done multiple times, this solution might be lacking, simply because of a lack in documentation.

Just applying regex to a file (maybe not even saving it) is not really reproducible / understandable for others.

I'm proposing a python small script to make clear what you are in fact doing. Besides you'll get full control over the exact format of the output, where it writes to etc.

```
# get regex module
import re

filename = 'path/to/your/file.txt'

# open file
with open(filename) as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        # remove trailing whitespace
        line = line.strip()

        # if line is empty forget about it
        if not line:
            continue

        # split into comment part and data part
        data, comment = line.split(';')

        # transform into comma seperated values
        # aka. remove whitespace, parentheses, quotes
        data = re.sub(r'\s|\(|\)|\'', '', line)

        # file is build up like this (TODO: make names more logical)
        nr1, nr2, nr3,                                                         \
        name,                                                                  \
        hash1, hash2, hash3,                                                   \
        first_date, discoverer, nr4,                                           \
        category, snapshot_file, last_date = data.split(',')

        # print, or possibly write
        print("{name:}, {hash1:}, {hash2:}, {hash3:} {comment:}".format(**locals()))
```

Comment: just now read your comment about writing in C++, something similar can of course also be done in that language.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a comma-delimited file, you can use a regular expression to search and replace, although it won't be nearly as efficient as just splitting up your string in your programming language of voice.

```
'([^']*)',\s*
```

will find a single quote, then capture all the text until it encounters the next single quote, followed by the comma and any trailing whitespace.

You would then repeat that a bunch of times, once for each comma-separated field.

It would look a little [like this](https://regex101.com/r/uG5tN7/1), and then you can choose which fields to substitute back into your text. In this case, you want only fields `\4` through `\8`.

Could it be written so the `\1` through `\3` are not captured? Certainly, using a non-capturing `(?:...)` group. Then your substitutions would range from `\1` through `\5`. But this makes it flexible enough that if you want to include or exclude any of the other fields, it's as simple as including or excluding them in the substitution field.

Comment: But how can I do it in Notepad++?

Comment: Just get rid of the [extra whitespace in the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/uG5tN7/2). Knowing that this is in Notepad++ (or any other engine/editor/language) is helpful to know up front so we know whether or not to tailor our responses in any specific way.